# put mapbox-gl in a worker and read with readpixels() to encode in the main thread

Tags: webgl, mapbox, web-worker, video-encoding, offscreen-canvas

This is the first time I've asked a question on Stackoverflow and it's because I really got stuck. I have an animation in mapbox, which runs on the same thread as the h264-mp4-encoder video encoder. My code works and does the job, but during the rendering of the mapbox animation you see small jumps and sometimes vibrations and I am sure that it is because both tasks are carried out in the same thread. I tried to create a worker for encoding, but I have errors because the encoder needs the mapbox instance. I was looking into offscreencanvas but there isn't much information about working with webgl. Maybe you could recommend a different way to deal with that problem, either by sending the encoder to a worker or mapbox to another worker or even better if you opened up a better way to solve this.

```
 map.on("load", async () => {
        // add 3d, sky and fog
        add3D();
        await map.once("idle");
        // don't forget to enable WebAssembly SIMD in chrome://flags for faster encoding
        const supportsSIMD = await simd();
        // initialize H264 video encoder
        const Encoder = await loadEncoder({ simd: supportsSIMD });
        const gl = map.painter.context.gl;
        const width =
          gl.drawingBufferWidth % 2 === 0
            ? gl.drawingBufferWidth
            : gl.drawingBufferWidth - 1;
        const height =
          gl.drawingBufferHeight % 2 === 0
            ? gl.drawingBufferHeight
            : gl.drawingBufferHeight - 1;

        //create encoder
        const encoder = Encoder.create({
          width,
          height,
          fps: 30,
          kbps: 2200,
          rgbFlipY: true,
        });
        // stub performance.now for deterministic rendering per-frame (only available in dev build)
        let now = performance.now();
        //mapboxgl.setNow(now);
        const ptr = encoder.getRGBPointer(); // keep a pointer to encoder WebAssembly heap memory
        function frame() { //this function is called to read the pixels every time mapbox re-renders
          //increment stub time by 16.6ms (60 fps)
          now += 1000 / 30;
          mapboxgl.setNow(now);
          const pixels = encoder.memory().subarray(ptr); // get a view into encoder memory
          gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels); // read pixels into encoder
          console.log("inicia");
          encoder.encodeRGBPointer(); // encode the frame
        }
        map.on("render", frame); // set up frame-by-frame

        await playAnimations(geojson);//a call is made to the map animation function
        // stop recording
        map.off("render", frame);
        mapboxgl.restoreNow();
        setIsRunAnimate(false);
        //encoded video
        const mp4Blob = encoder.end();
        setVideoBlob(mp4Blob);
})
```

This is a worker who believes, thinking he could achieve it. What I tried was to read the pixels inside the worker and encode it, but it gives me an error because it requires mapboxgl.

```
// encoderWorker.js

let encoding = false;
let now = performance.now();
let ptr;

onmessage = async (event) => {
  const { width, height, fps, kbps, rgbFlipY } = event.data;

  const { simd } = await import("wasm-feature-detect");
  const Encoder = await import("../../assets/convertidor.js");

  const encoder = Encoder.create({
    width,
    height,
    fps,
    kbps,
    rgbFlipY,
  });

  ptr = encoder.getRGBPointer();

  function encodeFrame() {
    now += 1000 / fps;
    mapboxgl.setNow(now);
    const pixels = encoder.memory().subarray(ptr);
    encoder.encodeRGBPointer();
  }

  onmessage = (event) => {
    const { type } = event.data;
    if (type === "start" && !encoding) {
      // Start coding/frame-by-frame
      encoding = true;
      encodeFrame();
      requestAnimationFrame(encodeFrame);
    } else if (type === "finish" && encoding) {
      // Stop encryption
      encoding = false;

      // Return the encoded blob to the main thread
      const encodedBlob = encoder.end();
      postMessage({ type: "complete", encodedBlob });
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: I'd use two ArrayBuffers, one you'll write to from the canvas, and then transfer to the Worker thread before copying it to your WASM buffer, and finally transfer back to the main thread so that you can write the next canvas frame.

Comment: So would I have to keep the rendering on the main thread? Doing the tests I see that the only lines that are causing the problem are: gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels); // read pixels into encoder. and also: encoder.encodeRGBPointer(); When commenting on these two lines, the animation is carried out completely normally. The readpixels() process is what hits the animation the most.

Comment: I guess, you can also move it to another worker thread, I don't know mapbox nor if their API has been made context agnostic or not. But yes, assuming that doing everything (including the readPixel) but the encoding works fine, then you'd want to separate the encoding and the mapbox (+ pixelRead) in different threads. And for this you'd need to copy the buffer used to read the canvas pixels into the WASM buffer (because we can't transfer WASM buffers).